# How to enter data from a ListBox into an Access Database for each item in the ListBox? Only the first item is going into the database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I'm creating a form of an assignment and it requires me to make a user-friendly form in which the user can order products. Once the order is confirmed, the data in the ListBox should appear in the access database for each line in the ListBox. However, only the first line in the ListBox appears in the Access database.

Here is an image of the form:
[image]

The code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmOrderProduct
    Dim iPadCasePrice As String
    Dim iPad2Price As String
    Dim prod_list As List(Of String)
    Dim Total As Decimal
    Dim EachItemTotalPrice As Decimal
    Dim Quantity As Integer
    Dim PriceEach As Decimal

    Private Sub frmOrderProduct_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Call connection()

        cmboxProduct.Items.Add("iPad Case")
        cmboxProduct.Items.Add("iPad 2")


        iPadCasePrice = "$20"
        iPad2Price = "$200"


        txtUsername.Text = frmLogin.txtUsername.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddToCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddToCart.Click

        Dim PricePerLine As Decimal

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "" Or txtQuantity.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill out all required fields", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid entered data")
        Else

            PricePerLine = txtQuantity.Text * txtPriceEach.Text
            ListBoxCart.Items.Add("x" & txtQuantity.Text & " " & cmboxProduct.SelectedItem & " " & txtPriceEach.Text & " " & "$" & PricePerLine)

            Quantity = Decimal.Parse(txtQuantity.Text)
            PriceEach = Decimal.Parse(txtPriceEach.Text.Remove(0, 1)) 'need to remove the $ before parse
            Total += PriceEach * Quantity
            txtTotalPrice.Text = String.Format("${0}", Total)


            'txtShoppingCart.AppendText("x" & txtQuantity.Text & " " & Product1 & Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtQuantity_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtQuantity.KeyPress

        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOrderProducts_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOrderProducts.Click

        Dim numberOfItems = ListBoxCart.Items.Count
        For Each item As String In ListBoxCart.Items

            Try

                cm = New OleDbCommand
                With cm
                    .Connection = cn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblOrders ([ProductName],[Quantity],[PriceEach],[OrderTotalPrice],[PricePerLine],[Username]) VALUES (@ProductName,@Quantity,@PriceEach,@TotalPrice,@PricePerLine,@Username)"

                    prod_list = item.Split(" ").ToList
                    'Dim NumberOfSpaces = " ".Count
                    'Dim NumberOfElements = NumberOfSpaces + 1
                    'prod_name = prod_list.ElementAt(Number of elements - 2)
                    Dim prod_name = prod_list.ElementAt(1) & " " & prod_list.ElementAt(2)
                    Dim prod_quantity = Integer.Parse(prod_list.ElementAt(0).Remove(0, 1))
                    Dim price_each = prod_list.ElementAt(3).Replace("$"c, "")
                    Dim PricePerLine = prod_list.ElementAt(4).Replace("$"c, "")
                    'EachItemTotalPrice = Quantity * PriceEach

                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ProductName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, prod_name))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Quantity", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, prod_quantity))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@PriceEach", OleDbType.Currency, 255, price_each))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@OrderTotalPrice", OleDbType.Currency, 255, Total))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@PricePerLine", OleDbType.Currency, 255, PricePerLine))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, txtUsername.Text))
                    prod_list = New List(Of String)

                    cm.Parameters("@ProductName").Value = prod_name
                    cm.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = prod_quantity
                    cm.Parameters("@PriceEach").Value = CDec(price_each)
                    cm.Parameters("@OrderTotalPrice").Value = Total
                    cm.Parameters("@PricePerLine").Value = CDec(PricePerLine)
                    cm.Parameters("@Username").Value = txtUsername.Text


                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = ""
                    txtQuantity.Text = ""
                    txtTotalPrice.Text = ""
                    ListBoxCart.Items.Clear()

                    Exit Sub
                    cn.Close()
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClearCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearCart.Click

        ListBoxCart.Items.Clear()
        Total = 0
        txtTotalPrice.Text = String.Empty

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmboxProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmboxProduct.SelectedIndexChanged

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "iPad Case" Then
            txtPriceEach.Text = iPadCasePrice
        End If

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "iPad 2" Then
            txtPriceEach.Text = iPad2Price
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is a wonderful and marvelous control for DB Ops called the `DataGridView`.  It keeps data elements separate so you dont have to chop them up (or glue them together).  Using a proper `DataSource`, you can update, insert and/or delete many many items with *one line of code*.  As is, you cannot have stepped thru the code as it runs (debugged it) or you would see why it only adds one.  It is not too late to read [ask] and take the [tour] and perhaps [mcve]

Comment: I'm just a little scared of restarting this form >.< I don't know how a DataGridView works, and how I would input the data inside it into the database. Thank you! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be not a afraid.  There are hundreds and hundreds of posts here as well as several good articles at MSDN on `DataGridView`.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - all your posts have a score of 0 or less which will take its toll.  Besides, learning is fun

Comment: ...including the **essential** skill of debugging your own code to remove errors of logic you included

Comment: As Plutonix suggests, you REALLY need to learn how to debug. If you had done so, the issue would be obvious. You have a loop that is supposed to visit every item in your `ListBox` but at the bottom of that loop you clear that very same `ListBox` and exit the current method. How are you supposed to do anything with the other items if you do that after processing the first item?

Comment: As well as learning how to debug, you also need to learn how to plan your code. If you had written down what your code was supposed to do before writing it then you could have compared the code to that plan and there's no way that you would ever have planned to clear the `ListBox` after processing the first item so it would have been obvious that that code di not do what you planned. If you write code without planning and don't bother watching the code in action, of course you're going to make basic mistakes like that. Those are the first two lessons for beginners to learn.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try planning code out in pseudocode next time, we learnt it in class... better put it to use. Thank you for pointing out my stupid mistake.

Comment: this same question was put on hold Failed to convert parameter value from string to a decimal, how do I resolve this error? What does it mean? [on hold]

Comment: @jmcilhinney I just noticed, even when I removed that line that read "Listbox.clear()" Even with it removed my program only enters the first line in the ListBox into the database... Strange.

Comment: **Debug your code**.  We will not be available thru your entire career (or school term) to do it for you.  As was pointed out you also have an `Exit Sub` in there.  PLEASE read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: No, not strange. You still have an `Exit Sub` line so how is it strange that you only process one item if you exit the method after processing the first item?

Comment: If by *strange* you mean the code does exactly what you told it to do, then yes, that is strange.  Note that we were able to see that gaffe *because* after debugging a great deal of code, we have sort of developed a virtual compiler in our head.  Join us.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm actually so sorry, I'm very new to this all. It still doesn't work, but I'm gonna try and debug it. I'll get back if I discover another problem or not because it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Plutonix I've got a long way to go to becoming decent at this...

Comment: Also sorry to you, @jmcilhinney

Comment: Indeed, and your access to help here will get throttled soon if you dont implement some of the elements discussed in [ask], from the [help] and the [tour].  An interesting, descriptive title, [mcve] (emphasis on minimal - why do you think we need the `KeyPress` event code?) among other things.   But then you routinely ignore advice you get (such as saving calculated fields, so....  This also has nothing at all to do with access-vba

Comment: @Plutonix alright thank you, I'll use the resources available when asking questions in future. My program is frustrating me lol. Still isn't looping the way it's expected too. I've read through it like 10 times now xD

Comment: "reading thru it" is not debugging.  Debugging requires some elaborate and very complex tools: [F9], [F5], [F8] and The Mouse.  perhaps an additional window or two when you are ready for More

Comment: @Plutonix What exactly is [F9] doing? It seems to be highlighting some code in red, with a large red ball on the left next to the line.

Comment: Beyond the Power of Google and the Wonder of MSDN: **[Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**  Then read [ask] and take the [tour] (they will give you a shiny badge when you do!)

Comment: Where did you open your connection? You close your connection at the bottom of your loop. Of course it never did get closed because you Exit Sub before you close it. When you remove Exit Sub also move cn.Close() to outside your loop or reopen it before the next cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. Please don't tell me you opened it in Form Load.